# Book series where a main character can become invisible

Tags: story-identification

I read it approximately 15 years ago.

- The key character can become invisible.
- The protagonist is not a human.
- He has a small 'gnome type' sidekick creature that helps the main character

It’s not *Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: That's a bit vague.  Can you give a bit more information?

Comment: As @Chenmunka notes, awfully vague.  Additional info like when you read and/or when it might have been published ?  Targeted age - children, young adult, adult ?

Comment: It is at least 15 years ago it was published. I honestly done remember anything else. And I'm positive it is not the hobbit

Comment: @user41506 Can you tell whether the genre was fantasy or science fiction? And what do you mean by "small genome type sidekick"? Can you give some plot details or character details? Any other details to help make the story unique are much apreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142225/ya-coming-of-age-fantasy-series-protagonist-keeps-pigs (which is newer but is confirmed by OP comment)

Answer (score 4):

The book series sounds a lot like [The Chronicles of Prydain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Prydain).

It features a main character named Doli who was a dwarf/fairy creature who had the ability to turn invisible, though with great strain and would cause ringing and buzzing in his ears.

According to Wikipedia: "Doli is one of the "fair folk", a nation of faeries, and other magical beings who live in an extensive underground kingdom that spans the entire country of Prydain. Doli is described as a short, stocky dwarf who carries a number of weapons including a battleaxe. He is adept in many skills including hunting, fighting, as well as magical skills such as turning invisible."

There was also another character who was a hybrid of man/beast named Gurgi who could also be the 'gnome' type character that you mentioned in your question. If that gnome spoke in rhyming pairs like "crunchings and munchings" then I would definitely say your book series was this one.